# Azure webjobs output logs indexing taking very long

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a frequently running triggered webjob (every 3 minutes) and others that are triggered weekly/daily and some running continuously.

If I visit https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions the site takes forever to load as it tries to load and index function invocations and these get overwhelmed by the output from the frequent job.

My questions:

- How can I set the logging retention for a particular webjob?
- Anything I write to the console shows up in the Webjob run details page but nothing from the `TextWriter`. Since both outputs seem to get persisted, which is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no way currently to set the retention policy. Sorry. Feel free to open a bug here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk
2. Console messages end up in the webjob logs (the top level job). TextWriter messages end up in the function invocation log. If you write to console, you also have a concurrency issue because multiple functions can run at the same time so the logs might be mixed up.

Comment: Thanks, bug created [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/560)