# How to control and maintain Azure web jobs control panel logging?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am using azure web jobs in a system to process xml data received in real-time via a web service that is queued for later processing. Some of the webjob functions are invoked at quite a high frequency (100s per minute). When I first trialed the system the logging seemed to perform well. However now after several weeks a large volume of log data has accumulated it seems to stop updating and displays "indexing in process" fairly constantly.

1. How do I 'purge' or clear-out the logs?
2. Can I and should I turn off logging selectively for the frequently updated jobs? How can this be achieved?

My web jobs are continuous and use the c# api. My question isn't the same as [Azure webjobs output logs indexing taking very long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867532/azure-webjobs-output-logs-indexing-taking-very-long) although this answer is also relevant - I was specifically asking how to purge the logs and turn off logging selectively.

[image: Azure web jobs control panel logging]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure webjobs output logs indexing taking very long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867532/azure-webjobs-output-logs-indexing-taking-very-long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You would have configured the `AzureWebJobsStorage` application setting or connection string in your WebJob. The logs are stored in the blob storage of this storage account. You should be able to manually clear them up there.
2. Assuming that you are using the Azure WebJobs SDK, you can plug in a custom logger

   ```cs
   JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
   config.Tracing.Tracers.Add(new CustomTraceWriter(TraceLevel.Info));
   JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
   host.RunAndBlock();
   ```

   `CustomTraceWriter` can wrap all writes within a check for an application setting

```cs
    if(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("EnableWebJobLogging"))
    {
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks the CustomTraceWriter could be useful.

Comment: After some further investigation I discovered the following in the release notes: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Release-Notes#v111 - the TraceLevel attribute can be used to control dashboard logging granularity at a web job function level. Therefore applying:      [TraceLevel(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error)] to a function will cause only Errors to be logged to the dashboard. This is exactly what I am looking for.